# Unity3D Crash When Leaving Tango Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, google-project-tango

When leaving a scene that uses `Motion Tracking`, `Area Learning`, and `WebcamTexture` and moving to a menu scene that uses a standard `Camera` and no Tango prefabs, the application will crash.

```
02-25 13:32:46.285     886-1005/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '6510e8f0 com.google.atap.app/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
02-25 13:32:46.285     886-1005/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '6510e8f0 com.google.atap.app/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
02-25 13:32:46.292     165-5890/? E/Camera2-FrameProcessor﹕ get3aResult: Camera 0: No afState provided by HAL for frame 709!
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5896/? E/Surface﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5896/? E/Camera3-OutputStream﹕ returnBufferCheckedLocked: Stream 0: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5896/? E/Camera3-Device﹕ Can't return buffer 0 for frame 708 to its stream:  Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-OutputStream﹕ getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-Device﹕ RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-OutputStream﹕ getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-Device﹕ RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-OutputStream﹕ getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-Device﹕ RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-OutputStream﹕ getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-Device﹕ RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.308     165-5888/? E/Camera3-OutputStream﹕ getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
02-25 13:32:46.309      165-165/? W/CameraService﹕ Disconnecting camera client 0xb8ac5f40 since the binder for it died (this pid 165)
02-25 13:32:46.309      165-165/? I/Camera2Client﹕ stopPreviewL: stopPreview ++
02-25 13:32:46.309      183-670/? I/sensor-hub-uart﹕ sensor_hub_uart_msg_queue: 54 15 9 2 returned 0
02-25 13:32:46.309     183-5904/? I/sensor-hub-uart﹕ wrote 54:15:9:2 0 0 to 13
02-25 13:32:46.309     886-1131/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.google.atap.app (pid 5673) has died.
```

Is there any method that must be called when done using `Tango` prefabs and leaving the scene?  Any idea why the crash is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Unity, but at the C level you need to call TangoService_disconnect - if you don't do that, and you do have live callbacks, well, who knows what will happen  :-)

Comment: Good call.  Calling `TangoApplication.Shutdown();` before transitioning out of a scene will prevent the crash.  Thanks!